How to disable Tkinter button after click?
I want to be able to disable buttons after they're clicked once.
I already tried disabling my first button (called e_button) at the end of this: e_button = Button(root, text="Enter", command = lambda:[intro_dialogue(),first_choice()])
line of code. It disabled the button but it did so before I clicked it. So I tried disabling it in the first line of the intro_dialogue definition and I got an error. The error said something about there being too many things to unpack.
(Sorry if this is a basic or stupid question, I am new to python and programming in general.)

How can we identify the issue without a [mre] and the full error traceback? Also it is not recommended to call multiple functions inside a lambda.  Use a normal function to call those functions instead.

At the end of your first_choice function, just add a statement like this:
e_button["state"] = "disabled"
This disables the button so that once the button is clicked, it runs the intro_dialogue function, the first_choice function and then turns off the button.
